STM32 Over-The-Air update with SIM7682E LTE modem
I have a need to add an Over-The-Air firmware update feature to my project. It is based on STM32F103CBT6 and SIMCOM SIM7682E LTE modem.
The main idea is to connect to the FTP server or get the file via HTTP and apply the received firmware to the MCU. I see some troubles while trying to implement that feature and want to ask the community the best way to do that.

STM32F103CBT6 has 128 kB of Flash memory and the firmware is about 33-40 kB of size. I know that I need to make some partitions of the memory to store main firmware and the firmware that will be applied so sections of 64 kB will be okay.
I also know that I possibly need some bootloader for that but what should it do? Should it establish a communication with the modem, send AT commands to it and receive a file which will be applied or just replace received file from one partition to the another?
My MCU has only 20 kB of RAM and with current application I`m getting only around 1 kB of free RAM. With the solutions on the web I need to copy received data (firmware file) into some buffers which will be applied then. But could I copy received data directly into the flash? I mean will it be correct?
The last but not least - the firmware file receiving algorithm. I don`t know yet how to correctly get the file with STM32. After sending an AT command to the modem that I want to download a file, the modem starts to send all the data with the 1024 bytes packets until the end of the file.
How to properly process all of that data? And what type of the file should I use like .hex or .bin or what?

I will very appreciate any help and any your question. It will be great to create a thread where anyone could find answer to it`s question while developing it's own OTA feature.

You can also post this to stm forum if you do not get any answer here.
